# Maya - rendering without having to select a view first

Tags: maya

Maya is a fantastic software, but has one annoying thing: you always have to select a view when you want to render the current frame.

Is there a way to make one view permanent for rendering, so every time I select Render > Render Current Frame it stops to annoy me asking for the view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Window > Rendering Editors > Render View, you can use the button under the "File" menu option to redo the previous render (or an initial render I think). I've never rendered using the process you're using :)